# is there a way to fetch only the updated documents in openFDA?

Tags: api, openfda, drugs

I am using a query like the following one
[https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20110601+TO+20121231]&limit=1](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:%5B20110601+TO+20121231%5D&limit=1)
to search for all records with effective_time between Jun 01, 2011, and Dec 31, 2012

But, is there any way to fetch the records updated/created from a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are no "updates" to drug labels in the traditional sense -- any change in labeling information requires issuance of a new version of the SPL document. `effective_time` serves as a "creation date" for *that* particular version.

I think you can still rely on the `effective_time` field in your searches but also look at the value of the `version` field. Value of `1` would indicate "creation" in the traditional sense (initial issuance of the drug label), while values higher than `1` would indicate "updates". For example, here is a query for drug labels created since the beginning of the year:

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20210101+TO+20211231]+AND+version:%221%22](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:%5B20210101%20TO%2020211231%5D%20AND%20version:%221%22&limit=100)

Hope this helps.