How to get the date last updated for a drug label by id?
Is there any date offered by openFDA API, or other related sources, that shows when a specific drug label was last updated? By last updated, I mean when the content of this id was first returned by the API, not when the drug label was authored or went into effect.

There is meta.last_updated which is "the last time the openFDA API was itself updated".
There is effective_time which is "Date reference to the particular version of the labeling document." I see this set well into the future so it definitely is not when the data was last updated. For example, https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=set_id:77e51d6f-c1a2-4650-b3dd-5e4552379e77&limit=100 as of Nov 2024 shows effective time as 20250115 See https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/18489 which suggests effective_time


Unfortunately, such date is not currently offered by the  openFDA API.
